# How to create security groups in Azure AD using Automation?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have to create lot many access packages for different teams. Its very time taking to create groups or access packages.

Is there any way to create groups or access package automatically in AAD?

I basically mean, I will create the persona or groups ( with proper naming convention in excel or csv file) then give it (the excel/csv file) to automation and the automation Job will create the groups/access package. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

***To create security groups in Azure AD automatically, you can make use of "PowerShell".***

1. Please check whether you have **AzureAD** module installed or not. If not, install it using below command:

```
Install-Module AzureAD
```

2. Create a **`.csv file`** with below format including **Group Names** and their **Description**:

[image]

3. Make use of below ***PowerShell script*** to create AAD groups automatically:

```
$Groups = Import-Csv -Path C:\AzureAD_Groups.csv
 
foreach($Group in $Groups)
{
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName $Group.DisplayName -Description $Group.Description -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

***Security Groups are created automatically in Azure Active Directory like below:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[Creating Groups in Azure AD using PowerShell](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creating-groups-azure-ad-using-powershell-ewan-monro/?articleId=6506786193370423296)